# сортировка полиморфного дерева указателей

Tags: c++

Есть дерево, каждый элемент дерева описывается структурой:

```
class TreeItem
{
public:
   void sort();
...
protected:
   TreeItem* m_parent;
   std::vector<TreeItem*> m_children;
}
```

От этого класса пронаследованы уже уникальне реализации, каждая со своим набором полей дерева, типа

```
class MyItem1 : public TreeItem
```

...

```
class MyItemN : public TreeItem
```

Как можно отсортировать всё дерево с помощью вызова sort()?

Т.е. начиная с корня мы сортируем все вектора m_children с собственными функциями-сортировки.

Основной затуп в том, что в векторах лежат указатели и я как-то не могу реализовать полиморфизм для оператора <

```
void TreeItem::sort()
{
    // сортируем детей
    for (auto& child : m_children)
        child->sort();

    // А тут собственно я туплю )
    std::sort(m_children.begin(), m_children.end(),
        [](const TreeItem* a, const TreeItem* b) -> bool
    {
        return *a < *b; // можно ли тут как-то сделать < полиморфным, или сделать через доп. виртуальную функцию типа less(...)
    });
}
```

Если мы указатели просто разыменовываем, то это неправильно, т.к. там могут находится объекты класса MyItem1 .. MyItemN, а сравнивать просто укзатели это не совсем то, т.к. будет просто арифметическое сравнение адресов.

sort() можно сделать виртуальным, но как-то я запутался)

Дополниельно:
На каждом уровне дерева у нас располагаются объекты одинаковых классов.
Т.е. уровень 1 (root children) - класс MyItem1, уровень N - класс MyItemN

Код не обязателен, можно общий подход или ткните в ссылку, буду признателен

Comment: Ну если они одинакового класса, то просто кастуйте их в ссылку на этот класс и сравнивайте

Comment: У вас тут, похоже, вырисовывается двойная диспетчеризация. Решается такая проблема при помощи паттерна "Посетитель"

Comment: А как конкретно должно ваше `<` работать?

Comment: @holybkackcat, сравнивать в зависимости от полей класса, ид/ имя/код/другие данные, поля для каждого из классов реализации свои, сделать что-то общее и вынести в базовый класс не получается

Comment: Думаю... тут три варианта решения. От простого к сложному. 1)создать массив, поместить туда все ветви которые нужно сортировать. Массив отсортировать. 2) помещать по одной ветви в массив, с упорядовачиванием при добавлении. 3) делать "виртуальный" массив, который сможет обойти "сортировочная функция". Важно - что бы был линейный массив (т.е. то, от чего можно оттолкнуться), или псевдо-линейный (чуть сложнее). Иначе - нечего сортировать.

Comment: *можно ли тут как-то сделать < полиморфным* конечно можно. `class TreeItem{public: bool operator < (TreeItem& item)  { .... }` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Comment: @goldstar_labs Я спрашиваю, по какому принципу вы собираетесь определять, какой из объектов двух произвольных разных дочерних классов меньше другого, если у них поля разные.

Comment: @nick_n_a, уже сделал виртуальную функцию `less(const TreeItem*)`, которая все сравнивает. А как вообще правильно и красиво можно решить задачу сортировки дерева из различных элементов?

Comment: Если хочешь сравнивать через виртуальную функцию - то вызывай `less` явно (тогда не нужно знаки рисовать). Если хочешь сравнивать через оператор `<` то нужно обьявить оператор. Можно обьявить и то и то, и оператор пробросить на функцию.

Comment: @nick_n_a, а вы [пробовали](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d89d8d352a61776b) писать темплейтные виртуальные функции?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb нет. Исправлюсь. Шаблонные классы писал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша проблема называется "[Двойная диспетчеризация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4)". Если в двух словах, ситуация когда хотелось бы иметь виртуальную функцию сразу для описания взаимодействия двух классов. К сожалению(или к счастью), в С++ есть только одиночная диспетчеризация(виртуальные функции), так придется все писать руками.

---

Будем писать [посетителя](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)). У этога патерна есть недостаток - в коде нужно делать много изменений если иерархия часто меняется. Но в случае двойной диспетчеризации нам в любом случае при добавлении/удалении нового класса придется переписать кучу кода.

Начнем с интерфесов:

```
class IItemVisitor;

class IItem{
public:
    IItem() = default;
    IItem(const IItem &) = default;
    IItem& operator=(const IItem &) = default;
    IItem(IItem &&) = default;
    IItem& operator=(IItem &&) = default;
    virtual ~IItem() = default;

    //Принимем посетителя
    virtual void accept(IItemVisitor &visitor) const = 0;

    //Никтогда так не делайте. Я так написал только для краткости.
    virtual void print() const = 0;
};

class NameItem;
class NameValueItem;

class IItemVisitor{
public:
    IItemVisitor() = default;
    IItemVisitor(const IItemVisitor &) = default;
    IItemVisitor& operator=(const IItemVisitor &) = default;
    IItemVisitor(IItemVisitor &&) = default;
    IItemVisitor& operator=(IItemVisitor &&) = default;
    virtual ~IItemVisitor() = default;

    //Посещаем конкретные итемы
    //Тут должен быть отдельный метод для каждого наследника. 
    virtual void visit(const NameItem &item) = 0;
    virtual void visit(const NameValueItem &item) = 0;
};
```

Реализуем пару конкретных классов:

```
class NameItem : public IItem{
    std::string _name;
public:
    NameItem(const std::string &name):
        _name(name)
    {}
    const std::string& name() const{
        return _name;
    }
    void accept(IItemVisitor &visitor) const override{
        visitor.visit(*this);
    }
    void print() const override{
        std::cout << "NameItem;      " << _name << std::endl;
    }
};

class NameValueItem : public IItem{
    std::string _name;
    int _value;
public:
    NameValueItem(const std::string &name, int value):
        _name(name),
        _value(value)
    {}
    const std::string& name() const{
        return _name;
    }
    int value() const{
        return _value;
    }
    void accept(IItemVisitor &visitor) const override{
        visitor.visit(*this);
    }
    void print() const override{
        std::cout << "NameValueItem; " << _name << "/" << _value << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Теперь реализуем операцию "меньше":

```
template<class First>
class ItemLessVisitorHelper : public IItemVisitor{
    const First &_first;
    bool _result;
public:
    explicit ItemLessVisitorHelper(const First &first):
        _first(first)
    {}
    void visit(const NameItem &second) override{
        _result = _isLess(_first, second);
    }
    void visit(const NameValueItem &second) override{
        _result = _isLess(_first, second);
    }
    bool isLess(const IItem &second){
        //Реальный тип _first мы выяснили ниже в ItemLessVisitor
        //Теперь выясняем тип второго
        second.accept(*this);
        return _result;
    }
private:
    //Сравниваем имена
    static bool _isLess(const NameItem &first, const NameItem &second){
        return first.name() < second.name();
    }
    //Сравниваем имена. Если они равны NameValueItem всегда больше
    static bool _isLess(const NameItem &first, const NameValueItem &second){
        if(first.name() == second.name()){
            return true;
        }

        return first.name() < second.name();
    }
    //Сравниваем имена. Если они равны сравниваем значения
    static bool _isLess(const NameValueItem &first, const NameValueItem &second){
        if(first.name() == second.name()){
            return first.value() < second.value();
        }

        return first.name() < second.name();
    }
    //Сравниваем имена. Если они равны NameValueItem всегда больше
    static bool _isLess(const NameValueItem &first, const NameItem &second){
        if(first.name() == second.name()){
            return false;
        }

        return first.name() < second.name();
    }
};

class ItemLessVisitor : public IItemVisitor{
    bool _result;
    const IItem *_second;
public:
    void visit(const NameItem &first) override{
        _result = ItemLessVisitorHelper<NameItem>(first).isLess(*_second);
    }
    void visit(const NameValueItem &first) override{
        _result = ItemLessVisitorHelper<NameValueItem>(first).isLess(*_second);
    }
    bool isLess(const IItem &first, const IItem &second){
        _second = &second;
        first.accept(*this);
        return _result;
    }
};
```

`ItemLessVisitor` принимает два объекта `IItem`, сам посещает первый, тем самым узнает его реальный тип. Затем при помощи `ItemLessVisitorHelper` посещает второй, и выполняет операцию сравнения. Сравниваются объекты по имени и, если есть возможность, по значению.

В случе добавления/удаления наследников `IItem` нужно добавить/удалить методы `visit` в `IItemVisitor`, и следовательно в `ItemLessVisitor` и `ItemLessVisitorHelper`.

[Полный пример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/249f61f887672ef5)

**Суть**

Выясняем реальные типы объектов при помощи посетителей, и вызываем одну из перегрузок `_isLess`.

Код в ответе это только пример того, как эта идея может быть реализована. Наверняка под конкретную задачу понадобится что-то добавить или напоборот получиться упростить.

Comment: я не знаю как тут поставить 10 плюсов, но спасибо большое за ответ.